# Different styles of bullets of enumerate

Tags: beamer, lists, enumerate

I have an `enumerate` inside an `enumerate`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
   \item Item1
   \item Item2
   \begin{enumerate}
      \item Item2.
   \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The problem is the bullets of the inner enumerate and the outer enumerate are in same style (a ball in green), does anyone know if there are other styles of bullets available?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There are four predefined styles: `ball`, `circle`, `square` and `default`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
   \item Item1
   \item Item2
  \setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[square]
   \begin{enumerate}
    \item Item2.
   \end{enumerate}
  \setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
   \begin{enumerate}
    \item Item2.
   \end{enumerate}
  \setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[circle]
   \begin{enumerate}
    \item Item2.
   \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Appropriately redefining some other templates you can change also the colors (and fonts):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{enumerate}
   \item Item1
   \item Item2
  \setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[square]
  \setbeamercolor{item projected}{bg=green!70!black,fg=blue}
   \begin{enumerate}
    \item Item2.
   \end{enumerate}
  \setbeamercolor{enumerate subitem}{fg=red!80!black}
  \setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
   \begin{enumerate}
    \item Item2.
   \end{enumerate}
  \setbeamercolor{item projected}{bg=magenta!70!black,fg=white}
  \setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[circle]
   \begin{enumerate}
    \item Item2.
   \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works fine. Anyway, I have tested it and found that there is no effect if I change the enumerate item from number to alphabet. For instance, `\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[square]` and `\begin{enunerate}[a]`

Comment: Is it possible to change the font size inside the ball or sphere? I presume the sphere size should also be changed.

Comment: In the case of enumerate, how could we then refer to bullet one in the text using the same style (e.g. a 1 inside a ball)?

Comment: `\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]` absolutely saved my bacon man, thanks!