# Beamer font and bullets

Tags: beamer

I want to prepare my presentation's outline page look like [this](http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/~ghadafi/Slides/DTABS2.pdf). But, I can't figure out how to use square bullets and the font that slide uses. Can someone please be of my help?

Comment: Have you seen this question? It answers your query about square bullets: [Different styles of bullets of enumerate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68347/4778). As far as the font goes, see this question instead [How can I automatically determine fonts used in an image or PDF?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/374)